# Function returning table. Want to compare each row with different table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have one table named `Document`. I have 2 columns inside that: `Inventor` and `Attorney`. I want to find out rows that have Attorney = Inventor.

Sample data that fit the "definition" of Attorney = Inventor are:

```
Inventor: Tom Kaufmann
Attorney: Tom Kaufmann

Inventor: Kaufmann
Attorney: Kaufmann; Tom

Inventor: Kaufmann; T
Attorney: Kaufmann; Tom

Inventor: Kaufmann; Tom
Attorney: Kaufmann; T

Inventor: Kaufmann; Tom, Somi; Jack
Attorney: Kaufmann; Tom

Inventor: Kaufmann; Tom,
Attorney: Kaufmann; Tom, Somi; Jack
```

For all of the above cases we can say attorney = inventor. How do I compare it? I do have a split function (Table valued function) that can basically split data based on delimeter and return. I am thinking I should split the names and then create cursors to process each row and compare it with other row. But that would result in too many cursors and can get messy. Does anybody have any better way of comparing these data? I hope you got my question. If not, please let me know.

Comment: I didnt get it. Please explain your sample data and the criteria to match `Inventor` and `Attorney`. `Attorney` and `Inventor` columns are varchar? What `;` delimiter means? What `,` delimiter means?

Comment: I think he wants a loose definition of =.  Jack you need to not use = as it has specific meaning.   You are looking for a match operator such that you would get a match in all the following.

Answer (score 0):

This might do it for you.   You will need to swap out the column names.  It basically just matches the positions up the to shortest

```
where  SUBSTRING(caseID  ,1, CASE WHEN len(mimeType) < len(caseID) THEN len(mimeType) else len(caseID) END) 
   =   SUBSTRING(mimeType,1, CASE WHEN len(mimeType) < len(caseID) THEN len(mimeType) else len(caseID) END)
```